# Mails do not properly sync between Apple Mail and the iCloud webmail

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, email

Any emails that I send/receive using Apple Mail on my Mac mini are not accessible via iCloud webmail. However, any mails I send/receive using the webmail *do* show up in Apple Mail.

For example, I need to look up information contained in an email I received in Apple Mail last year, but to do that I need to be using the OSX Mail app, as the required message simply doesn't exist as far as iCloud webmail is concerned.

I'm still running 10.6.8 on my mini - will that be the issue? Or have I just not switched on a needed setting in Mail?

Comment: Do you have more than one email address and is the email sent to  one of x@icloud.com, x@me.com or x@mac.com ?

Comment: Does 10.6.8 have native iCloud support?